# HTML5 video player mobile Safari doesn't respect z-index element overlay

Tags: ios, css, html, cordova, safari

On iOS I am trying to overlay custom buttons (like end call, mute, etc.) on my HTML5 video, which is used for a webrtc video chat. I tried making the body background transparent and added `transform-style: preserve-3d;` to the video elements, but even if I add `z-index:999999999999999` to the overlay custom buttons, it still doesn't go over the HTML5 video player

Comment: Can you give us a demo of what you tried that isn't working?

Comment: Do the buttons also have the 'position: relative' rule?